# Android 6.0 Marshmallow - Service not starting on test with API 23, works fine on API 21

Tags: java, android

I have the following test Service. It runs fine on API 21, but on API 23 the service doesn't start.

I have gone through the API change docs, but cannot see anything like changes to registration, etc.

This exact code is working on API 21. What am I missing?

Manifest segment:

```
<service
    android:name="com.mytest.service.TestService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

MainActivity segment:

```
this.startService(new Intent(this, TestService.class));
```

Service:

```
public class TestService extends Service
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d("OOP", "onstartTest");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `android:permission="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"`. You do not need it, as your service is not exported, so no third-party app can talk to that service anyway.

My guess is that your app does not hold that permission, as the user has not manually gone in and allowed your app to draw over top of other apps (via Settings).

Comment: I removed the permission from the manifest, and now the service loads. However, will this not introduce issues on lower APIs?

Comment: @spuriosity: No, because your service is still not exported on lower APIs, and so no third-party app can talk to the service anyway. I have no idea why you have that attribute there.

Comment: This is a test service, the services in my app use more functionality. Removing the permissions in the manifest on my real services now allows them to throw security exceptions. But if I implement the new model with dialog boxes etc., how is that backwards compatible with API 21 and less?

Comment: @spuriosity: "But if I implement the new model with dialog boxes etc., how is that backwards compatible with API 21 and less?" -- there is a ton written about that, and it is beyond the scope of your original question anyway. I suggest that you start with [this part of the developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), and note the use of `...Compat` classes for backwards compatibility. Note, though, that `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` is handled differently than most `dangerous` permissions, should you have a `<uses-permission>` element for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to declare a permission explicitly for your test, here is an example to declare Coarse Location Permission from test for Marshmallow:

```
private void requestUserPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
        displayCoarseLocationPermissionExplanation();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivityNameWherePermissionIsNeeded.this,
                                          new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                          PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
}
```